# How to configure a key vault in Azure after UseAzureKeyVault() was deprecated?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-keyvault

so I got a legacy C# project which I went on to upgrade the dependencies of, and for the creation of Azure key vault, it used the following lines of code:

```
public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureAppConfigurationWithKeyVault(this IConfigurationBuilder config, Action<AzureAppConfigurationOptions> action = null)
    {
        var settings = config.Build();

        return config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
        {
            var endpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_APP_CONFIGURATION_ENDPOINT") ?? settings["AzureAppConfiguration:Endpoint"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpoint))
            {
                throw new ConfigurationException("You must set an Azure App Configuration endpoint using the AZURE_APP_CONFIGURATION_ENDPOINT environment variable OR the AzureAppConfiguration:Endpoint settings key.");
            }

            // Connect to the Azure App Configuration store with the given
            // endpoint and add an Azure Key Vault client so we can resolve
            // Key Vault references.
            options.Connect(new Uri(endpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential())
                .UseAzureKeyVault(CreateKeyVaultClient());
               

            action?.Invoke(options);
        });

        static KeyVaultClient CreateKeyVaultClient()
        {
            var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
            var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecret))
            {
                // Use client credentials for Key Vault authentication, see
                // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core
                return new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
                {
                    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
                    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);

                    var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

                    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
                });
            }

            // Use Azure Managed Identity for Key Vault authentication, see
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/keyvault-msi-appservice-sample/
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var authenticationCallback = new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback);

            return new KeyVaultClient(authenticationCallback);
        }
    }
```

However, as I upgraded the dependencies, the UseAzureKeyVault() method was deprecated and substituted for a [ConfigureKeyVault()](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration-DotnetProvider/commit/d0da5dcc500c9e1edfcfddf38893102fc8c34061#diff-3be003e0f55525c62cbeec2d6654e63f), creating a need for this whole algorithm to be refactored.

**The question:** I cannot really get my head around this refactoring, as the return types for those methods are completely different. Using [code snippets suggestions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x) I came u with this (there are EnvVars in the project):

```
options.Connect(new Uri(endpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential())
               //.UseAzureKeyVault(CreateKeyVaultClient());
               .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
               {
                   kv.SetCredential(new EnvironmentCredential());
               });


            action?.Invoke(options);
```

However, what I am not sure of is the CreateKeyVaultClient() method now, can I delete it? Do I only initialize the EnvironmentCredential which will drain the env variables by itself and the whole process would work? or why do I need this KeyVaultClient, what is the story behind all this? cannot get my head around this Azure stuff for quite a while..

Thank you for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Azure App configuration together with key vault then this configuration works for us, please note that we use Managed Identities to handle the access right to the config store and key vault.

```
 builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddAzureAppConfiguration((options) =>
                {
                    options
                        .Connect(
                            new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("configurationStorePrimaryEndpoint")),
                            credentials
                        )
                        .ConfigureKeyVault(kv => kv.SetCredential(credentials))
                        .Select(keyFilter, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("envLabel"))
                        .TrimKeyPrefix(keyPrefix);
                });
```